# WIN 10 (previously dual boot) : grub cli showing before startup (hdd is 1st boot option)

Tags: boot, bios, grub

I ' ve used my computer (dell) with both ubuntu and win 10 in dual boot, but I recently remove the ubuntu partition.

Since then, on every start, i've 3 times "`checking media`" message shown ( with "fail" after a few seconds) ; then a grub command line shows up, I have to type "exit" in order to access the following screen : 
[image: start options]

I select the first one and only then, windows will load.

I've read about the onboard lan options that could cause the checking media message, but the 1st boot option in my BIOS is HDD.

[image]

After removing the linux partition, I've removed from the bios a related boot option, but it did not solve the problem...

I tried to add a new boot option, but did not find any available file!

Any help would be precious, I try ot to attempt anything on my own in order not to get stuck with a computer that wont even be able to launch windows...

( I've tried `restore factory default` option, but no change )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Answer is adopted from [Dell Support](https://www.dell.com/support/article/se/sv/sebsdt1/sln300987/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-on-a-gpt-hdd-for-windows-7-8-81-and-10-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en) for Windows 10, the same link provides a solution for other windows' too.

> You can also do it from windows `cmd` mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/869888/696880)

The GPT structure deals with a lot of the problems that the Bootsect command was designed to remedy in MBR. However if you find yourself in need of repairing the EFI bootloader, you can follow the instructions below :

### If you do have the Installation Media :

Insert the Media (DVD/USB) in your PC and restart.

Boot from the media.

Select Repair Your Computer.

Select Troubleshoot.

Select Advanced Options.

Choose Command Prompt from the menu :

Type and run the command :

```
diskpart
```

Type and run the command :

```
sel disk 0
```

Type and run the command :

```
list vol
```

Verify that the EFI partition (EPS - EFI System Partition) is using the FAT32 file system and assign a drive letter to it (Assign a letter that isn't already in use.):

Type and run the command :

```
sel vol <number of volume>
```

Type and run the command :

```
assign letter=<drive letter>:
```

Type and run the command :

```
exit
```

In order to repair the boot record :

Type and run the command :

```
cd /d <drive letter>:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\
```

Type and run the command :

```
bootrec /FixBoot
```

### If you don't have the Installation Media :

Restart your PC

Tap rapidly on the  key once the PC has turned on, but before the Windows Splash Screen appears.

Please be aware this may take several attempts. The timing for this option was shortened significantly from that in Windows 7.

Select Repair your computer from the menu that appears.

Select Command Prompt from the Advanced Options tab in the Troubleshoot screen :

Type and run the command :

```
diskpart
```

Type and run the command :

```
sel disk 0
```

Type and run the command :

```
list vol
```

Verify that the EFI partition (EPS) is using the FAT32 file system and assign a drive letter to it (Assign a letter that isn't already in use.):

Type and run the command :

```
sel vol <number of volume>
```

Type and run the command :

```
assign letter=<drive letter>:
```

Type and run the command :

```
exit
```

In order to repair the boot record :

Type and run the command :

```
cd /d <drive letter>:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\
```

Type and run the command :

`bootrec /FixBoo`t
The next step is the same across all the operating systems at this point :

Rebuild the BCD store

First run the command below to backup the old BCD :

```
ren BCD BCD.old
```

Now recreate it using this command :

```
bcdboot c:\Windows /l en-us /s <boot letter>: All
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but the next start did not change, even if all the commands you gave me returned succes mesages. I then added "-" signs in front of onboard IP4 and IP6 boot options in BIOS, that make quite no sense with no explanation... and now it works well. I will mark your answer because it might have been part of the solution ! good day

Comment: Good that it gave you hint, and now you have solved the problem. Good luck